# Update an attribute in a struct with reflection

Tags: go, struct, reflection

Is it possible to update an attribute in a struct based?

Would it be possible to do it based on its JSON tag?

Supposing a simple structure:

```
type User struct {
    Name string `json:"username"`
}
```

I need to update the `Name` attribute *programmatically* using reflection. I tried the following:

```
user := User{Name: "John"}
obj := reflect.Indirect(reflect.ValueOf(user))
obj.FieldByName("Name").SetString("Jake")
```

`panic: reflect: reflect.Value.SetString using unaddressable value`
https://play.golang.org/p/gkBgRXwje57

Comment: For further reading on reflection:https://blog.golang.org/laws-of-reflection

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To get an addressable value, pass the address of `user` to `reflect.ValueOf`:

```
user := User{Name: "John"}
obj := reflect.Indirect(reflect.ValueOf(&user))
obj.FieldByName("Name").SetString("Jake")
fmt.Println(user.Name)
```

It's known that the value is a pointer in this case, so call Elem() directly:

```
user := User{Name: "John"}
obj := reflect.ValueOf(&user).Elem()
obj.FieldByName("Name").SetString("Jake")
fmt.Println(user.Name)
```